# Can not seek into a file using 1 in the [whence] part and write something simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I open a file using the following code:

```
n_val = "Good Bad"
open = testfile.py
outputFile=open(outFile,"r+")
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.seek(-1,1)
outputFile.write(n_val)
```

then the following gives error:
outputFile.seek(-1,1)
io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks

But when I open the file using the following code:

```
n_val = "Good Bad"
open = testfile.py
outputFile=open(outFile,"br+") //I just open the file in binary mode
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.seek(-1,1)
outputFile.write(n_val)
```

then the following gives error:
outputFile.write(n_val)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Please give me a solution where I can use both the functions as to seek at a given condition and then write something to the file opened.

Comment: If you open in binary mode the you can only write bytes objects, not multi-byte strings.

Comment: Very interesting that cursor-relative `seek()`s are unsupported in text files (confirmed this under Windows - I suspect this has to do with Windows' multi-byte newlines `\r\n`). Can anyone confirm that other OSes don't have that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the string before you can write it to a binary file:

```
outputFile=open(outFile,"br+") //I just open the file in binary mode
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.read(1)
outputFile.seek(-1,1)
outputFile.write(n_val.encode("ascii"))
```

(or another encoding like `"utf-8"`, whatever your strings require)